# How to get elements in multi diementional array if one array's elements are not in another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have two arrays in PHP as follows:

*approval_users:*

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 2 [username] => aamir [remark] => as
approved [levels] => 1 [status] => Approved ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] =>
[username] => easy [remark] => [levels] => 2 [status] => - ));
```

*approved_users*

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 2 [username] => aamir [remark] => as
approved [status] => Approved ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 3 [username] =>
demo [remark] => as approved [status] => Approved ));
```

How do I get the user_id of array in *approved_users*,  which is not available in *approval_users* ?

In this example, it should return the array

```
[1] => Array ( [user_id] => 3 [username] =>
demo [remark] => as approved [status] => Approved ).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$results` below will contain what you want:

```
// list of all IDs in $approval_users
$approval_users_ids = array_column($approval_users, 'user_id');
$results = [];

foreach($approved_users as $user){
    //if current approved_user is not found in the list, add it to results
    if(!in_array($user['user_id'],$approval_users_ids)) $results[]=$user;
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/q26Ii)